# Physical/geometrical interpretations of spinors?

Tags: quantum-spin, group-theory, group-representations, spinors, clifford-algebra

Physically, a scalar is a quantity invariant with reference frame, a vector is a quantity associated with a direction, tensors are higher relationships between vectors - what are spinors? I thought I found an answer with clifford(/geometric) algebra, but apparently the use of the word spinor in that literature is highly non-standard. I have a decent understanding of the geometry of spacetime, and quantum mechanics, if that's necessary.

Comment: Hi user6873235, Welcome to Phys.SE. Usually Phys.SE only allows one subquestion per post, so I removed one of the subquestions.

Comment: I would suggest reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.3824.pdf) which provides a geometric description of spinors in a way that's meant to be intuitive.

Comment: I agree there a huge amount of literature on spinors and Clifford algebra. This is totally frustrating how differently they explain using different notation and approaches. The best ever book written on this topic that I would recommend is "Clifford Algebras and Spinors" by Pertti Lounesto.